# Inserting new column with particular character keeping lines of a particular length

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have to insert a column after the fourth column with the character 'A'.

Each line must have exactly 80 characters (including spaces) before the new line; if not we can add spaces to equalise. I have to do this for a large number of files.

Example representation of a single file:

Before:

```
ATOM    558  O   VAL    86     -12.863  -8.701 -49.495  1.00 64.57           O
ATOM    560  CA  VAL    87     -13.628 -10.486 -47.550  1.00 58.11           C 
.....
.....
.....
```

After:

```
ATOM    558  O   VAL A  86     -12.863  -8.701 -49.495  1.00 64.57           O  
ATOM    560  CA  VAL A  87     -13.628 -10.486 -47.550  1.00 58.11           C  
.......
.......
```

Comment: How about `sed -i 's/VAL  /VAL A/' filename`? Test it without `-i`, the output will then be shown in the terminal. If there's not a column with “VAL” before your desired column, you need to give more information about the different inputs.

Comment: If you can't use the above for some reason, explain why. `sed` takes as many file arguments as you like (eg use `*` for all non-hidden files in the current directory) - or perhaps your file is actually tab-separated or the specified char doesn't always need to go after `VAL`?

Comment: this VAL is not constant (it can be any character) in all files it may vary.. My requirement  is have to insert new column beside after 4th coulmn

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can just replace one space in column 5?

```
$ sed 's/  / A/5' file
ATOM    558  O   VAL A  86     -12.863  -8.701 -49.495  1.00 64.57           O
ATOM    560  CA  VAL A  87     -13.628 -10.486 -47.550  1.00 58.11           C
```

You can pass multiple filenames to `sed`, just use a shell glob like `*.txt` or whatever will catch the files you want to edit.

Use the `-i` flag after testing to modify the files.

This won't change the characters per line... If you need to pad the lines to 80 characters, you can use something like

```
sed 's/  / A/5' file | awk '{printf "%-80s\n", $0}'
```

Comment: its working but we have to check each line consist of 80 character,  including space. Now its only 78 character.. How could i do this for more than a lakh file consist in a folder at a time. How to put in for loop? I just ran for single file.

Comment: no its not working properly. its producing new line between each line and A column is occurring only at particular column.ATOM    585  CA  GLY A  90     -13.860 -10.427 -52.700  1.00 25.12           C
 
ATOM    587  O   GLY A  90     -14.834 -12.085 -54.087  1.00 25.12           O
 
ATOM    600  ND1 HIS   A93     -13.292 -11.141 -58.744  1.00 46.53           N
 
ATOM    601  CG  HIS A  93     -13.920 -10.048 -58.188  1.00 46.53           C

Answer (score 2):

Using `perl`:

```
perl  -lane '$"="\t"; print sprintf("%-80s", "@F[0..3]\tA\t@F[4..10]");' file
```

The output:

```
ATOM    558     O       VAL     A       86      -12.863 -8.701  -49.495 1.00    64.57   O                         
ATOM    560     CA      VAL     A       87      -13.628 -10.486 -47.550 1.00    58.11   C
```

To check that the length is exactly "80", pass the output to `awk '{ print length($0), "->", $0 }'`:

```
$ perl ... | awk '{ print length($0), "->", $0 }'
80 -> ATOM      558     O       VAL     A       86      -12.863 -8.701  -49.495 1.00    64.57   O                         
80 -> ATOM      560     CA      VAL     A       87      -13.628 -10.486 -47.550 1.00    58.11   C
```